# I am using the script to correctly position the anchor on the top. How do I properly position, from another page?

Tags: javascript, anchor

I am using the script below to correctly position the anchor on the top.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var $target = $(this.hash);
            $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if ($target.length) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - 135;
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });             
});
</script>
```

How do I properly position (height from the top), from another page?

Thank you.

Comment: What does it mean to `position (height from the top), from another page`?

Comment: If you really mean another page then we're talking websockets here...

Comment: I have a menu at the top which occupied 135px.
When I choose an option that is at the bottom of the page the anchor is positioned next to the drop-down menu, respecting 135px from the top to the bottom of the dropdown menu.
`var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - 135;`
But when I access the anchor from another page, 135px are not respected.